# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\sinh(x)^3\cosh(x)^4\ dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am experiencing some problems with solving the following definite integral:
$\int_{0}^{1}\sinh(x)^3\cosh(x)^4\ dx$

Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: rewrite $\sinh^3 x$ as $\sinh x \cdot \sinh^2 x$ and use the identity $\sinh^2 x=\cosh^2 x-1$

Comment: It's ultimately just a sum of exponentials, which is easy to integrate.

Comment: $$ \int ( \clubsuit ^2-1) \clubsuit ^4\, \mathrm{d}  \clubsuit $$

Comment: What @SineoftheTime said.  We can easily integrate $\int (\sinh x)^a (\cosh x)^b\,dx$ using that method when at least one of $a,b$ is an odd integer.

Comment: @GEdgar, Is it $sinh(x^3)$ or $(sinhx)^3$

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi ... if you want $\sinh(x^3)$, then put the $3$ inside the parentheses.  This case $\sinh(x)^3$ means $(\sinh x )^3$.

Comment: Show your effort and tell us where you stuck.

Comment: if you add what you've tried, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1):

It's not so hard if you remember the definition of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sinh(x)^3\cosh(x)^4\ \mathrm{d}x$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}\right)^3\left(\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}\right)^4\ \mathrm{d}x$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}\right)^3\left(\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}\right)^4\ \mathrm{d}x$$
$$\frac{1}{128}\int_0^1 \left(- e^{-7 x} - e^{-5 x} + 3 e^{-3 x} + 3 e^{-x} - 3 e^x - 3 e^{3 x} + e^{5 x} + e^{7 x}\right)$$
Etc...
In general
$$\int_0^1 e^{ax}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{e^a-1}{a}$$

Comment: is it $sinh(x^3)$ or $(sinh(x))^3$

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi The second

Comment: Avoid answering [no clue question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions)